# Add style If element has specific sibling

Tags: html, css

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="unit">
   <span class="error"></span>
   <input type="text" class="textInput"/>
</div>
```

I add span only if validation restriction is broken.

thus if validation passed I render following html:

```
<div class="unit">       
   <input type="text" class="textInput"/>
</div>
```

Is there way in css to draw red border for input if it has sibling span with class `error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector

```
.error + input.textInput 
{
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following code:

```
.error + input.textInput {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This will select all .textInput nodes which are immediately preceded by a .error node.

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant border, not outline.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.unit span.error + input.textInput{border:1px solid red;}
```

or

```
.unit span.error + input.textInput{outline:1px solid red;}
```